# How can I (automatically) determine whether a Java source file contains a public class, and if so, its name?

Tags: java

Say I have a .java file which may or may not contain a public class. If a public class exists, Java will refuse to compile this source file unless the filename matches the name of the public class. However, suppose that I don't **know** what the public class is called (or whether there is one at all). How can I determine this information automatically so that the file can be renamed appropriately and then compiled?

Comment: Who is writing uncompilable source code? Are you refactoring?

Comment: Since it is a .java couldn't you just open it in a text editor.. and read the code..

Comment: @user2494817 "automatically" is the key word

Comment: If you attempt to compile the file, the error will give you the class name.

Comment: Im not particularity sure but could you achieve these condition with reflections in java?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Parsing error messages doesn't seem like a very good solution. For example it could easily break if the wording changes when the Java compiler is upgraded.

Comment: @KumarKailash How would you reflect on a class that does not compile?

Comment: Use a parser, like the Java grammar available for ANTLR.

Answer (score 0):

If your code follows any reasonable coding style, any public class will be on a line of its own that reads

```
public /* maybe 'abstract' or 'final' */ class SomeClassName // maybe '{', maybe '// ...' or '/* ...'
```

So we can easily find a regular expression that matches and extracts it.

If you are on a POSIX system, a small bash script using grep should do the trick.  Do you need the code?

---

**Update:** I wanted to post this as a comment to someone else answer that suggested running the Java compiler and grep'ig for error messages but unfortunately, the answer was deleted again before I could comment:

You can also [run the compiler programmatically](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and catch the relevant exception.  However, you'll need to make sure the `CLASSPATH` is correct.  This means that the compilation order becomes significant.  That's why I hesitated to suggest this solution in the first place.

Comment: I want to avoid introducing an expectation that the code will have "reasonable coding style". If it matters, the code is intended to be run once and is unlikely to be inspected manually by anyone other than the person who wrote it in the first place.

Comment: Well, you can always run the Java compiler and see if it complains about “public class XYZ should be defined in a file named XYZ.java”.  If it does not complain, fine.  If it does, fix those five files manually or – if they are more and have a pattern – update your regular expression.  Of course, you can also write (or use) a complete Java parser to figure out whether there is such a class but isn't that a bit overkill?